# flash or silverlight websites without plugin

Tags: silverlight, flash

i want my websit ui of flash or silverlight quality, but want it to work on any browser by default, i.e not asking for installing flash plugin. is it possible ? what technology should i look at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on what kind of "UI quality" you have in mind.

If you want something static, pure HTML will do the job.

If you want dynamic UI, HTML + Javascript is probably your best option right now (AJAX if you need to deal with the server without refreshing the whole page).

HTML 5 will also offer you more UI possibilities if you don't mind waiting for it.

However, some plugins features (like 3D acceleration) will be difficult to "emulate" even with HTML 5, so before choosing which technology is suitable for you, defines whats your real UI needs are (for now and futur development).

Answer (score 0):

you could use javascript with a library such as jQuery to help. But there are things the both Flash and SilverLight can do that html+javascript just cannot do.

HTML5 is around the corner...Which to some extent can do a lot more...